# Possible capture group regex in order

Tags: regex

I'm writing a regex for a Swedish road sign time definition, which are written according to the followinging

```
Weekday
(Saturday)
Sunday (in red)
```

This is an example:

[image: Time example]

The spaces between the time and - are optional, some signs don't have it.
So I wrote this regex:

```
^\D?(?<WeekdayFrom>\d+)\s?-\s?(?<WeekdayTo>\d+).*+[\n]+\((?<SaturdayFrom>\d+)\s?-\s?(?<SaturdayTo>\d+)\)+[\n]+(?<SundayFrom>\d+)\s?-\s?(?<SundayTo>\d+)\s?$
```

However, this matches only part group of the following text:

```
18-17
(18-17)
9-20

9-22
(19-20)
```

It doesn't match the last group because it is missing the last capture group of `digit(space?)-(space?)digit`.

My question: How can I make these capture groups optional, but still distinguish them from each other? E.g. a weekday is a `digit-digit` with optional space in between where the next line must start with a `(` or no next line at all, and a Sunday is a `digit-digit` with optional space where the previous line must have ended with a `)` without any further digits behind it.

The sign can have more text before and after the time definition, but not in between. So it could be:

```
8-17
(9-13)
Avgift
Boende
```

or

```
9-19

3 tim
P-skiva
```

My example on regex101.com: https://regex101.com/r/C2NIPC/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes about the pattern:

- Using `\s` can also match a newline
- This part is a possessive quantifier `.*+` which you don't need, you can just use `.*` or for the example data omit it at all
- For the example data, you don't have to start the pattern with an optional non digit `\D?`
- The is a single newline after each line, so you could write `[\n]+` as `\n`

For this part to be true

*Sunday is a digit-digit with optional space where the previous line must have ended with a ) without any further digits behind it.*

you can make the Sunday part only match if there is a Saturday part:

```
^(?<WeekdayFrom>\d+) ?- ?(?<WeekdayTo>\d+)(?:\n\((?<SaturdayFrom>\d+) ?- ?(?<SaturdayTo>\d+)\)(?:\n(?<SundayFrom>\d+) ?- ?(?<SundayTo>\d+))?)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6moJHV/1)

Comment: Thank you very much for the notes; Regex has never been one of my strong sides, I am always struggling with it. This works very well.